# delete duplicated value in csv row [python pandas]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Given students.csv file looks like this:

```
studentid, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4
1,2,3,3,4
2,1,1,1,3
3,2,1,2,2
4,3,1,2,
```

Desired change to the csv once pandas is done with it is to remove any duplicates that come after the first instance of the value:

```
studentid, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4
1,2,3,,4
2,1,,,3
3,2,1,,
4,3,1,2,
```

I don't really have any idea how to write that code. Probably uses the pd.duplicated() function at some point, but not sure how it would look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.where` with `pandas.Series.duplicated`:

```
df = df.set_index("studentid")
new_df = df.where(~df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, 1), "").reset_index()
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   studentid  choice1 choice2 choice3 choice4
0          1        2       3               4
1          2        1                       3
2          3        2       1                
3          4        3       1       2
```

Comment: I found a bug the moment I hit accept - it's something I didn't think of myself until now - what if there is a choice with the same number as the studentid? I don't want the student ID being deleted. Just the values in the choice columns. Is there a quick modification to that?

Comment: @blindside044 Just make it as an index and do the same. I've updated the code accordingly